# How do I align two textboxes that are not nested similarly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

If you take a look at the HTML below you'll see I basically have two columns.

Both have a label and a input, and the first has an additional `img`.

You'll notice that the label for the first column wraps around pushing the two inputs out of alignment.

Without changing the basic structure of the two divs is there a way I can keep the two inputs aligned while also keeping the image in the first column below the first textbox?

I've tried doing stuff with absolute positioning and the bottom attribute, and while I can make it work if there's no image in the first column, I cannot make it work when there is.

If it's not possible with CSS can I do it with something like jQuery? Thanks for the help!

```css
  .flexForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.flexCol {
  flex-basis: 48.75%;
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flexForm">
    <div class="flexCol">
      <label>Username Label That Wraps</label>
      <input>
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=10&txt=50x50&w=50&h=50">
    </div>
    <div class="flexCol">
      <label>password</label>
      <input type="password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Even with the label wrapping your inputs line up.

Comment: For the problem to be seen, you need to disable `flex-wrap: wrap` from the code.

Comment: Without adjustments to the HTML, you'll need JavaScript. You're trying to align together children of flex items. There is nothing associating them, so they can't know what the other is doing.

Comment: Completely doable, however your misusing the flexible box model, I'll post shortly with a clear cut example, and your HTML should be SEMANTIC it's the ease, I'll show you!

Answer (score 0):

CSS only solution:

I had to modify your mark up a bit, I used naming conventions I'm used to. You can change that.

The idea was that I had a field wrapper, that contains three fields, regardless if the last field is empty.. Each field occupies 33% of the parent height. Therefore they will all line up nicely.

```css
/** MY CODE **/

.form {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

.form__column {
  height: 125px;
}

.field__wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.field {
  height: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<!-- MY CODE -->
<div class="form">
  <div class="form__column">
    <div class="field__wrapper">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Username Label Wraps. It's long.. </label>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=10&txt=50x50&w=50&h=50">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form__column">
    <div class="field__wrapper">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you miss _Without changing the basic structure of the two divs_?

Comment: @LGSon Did you miss the word "BASIC"? Adding wrappers doesn't change the structure. The structure remains the same. Changing the structure implies changing the DOM hierarchy which I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the parent container responsive by inheriting the width from it's children which are the ones that will be wrapping.

Also, if you aren't worried about SEO because your making some application which seems to be the case having a login page use semantic meaningful tags, you you don't get lost in `<div>` world.

```css
html{
 height: 100%;
}
html *{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
 margin: 0 !important;
 
 padding: 1em;

 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#41a3ff,#0273D4);
}
form{
 position: relative;
 padding: 1em;
 
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /*flex-start - whatever you want*/
 flex-wrap: wrap;

 
    background-color: #ECF0F1; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}
form > *{
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 margin: .5em;
 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
form > * > label{
/*  white-space: nowrap; */
}
form > button{
 top: 17px;
 height: 19px;
 
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0273D4;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #0089C4;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
}
form > button:hover{
 background-color: #0B9AD8;
}
form > button:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <form>
  <username>
   <label>Username Label That Wraps</label>
   <input></input>
   <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=10&txt=50x50&w=50&h=50">
  </username>
  <password>
   <label>password</label>
   <input></input>
  </password>
  <button type="submit">click me</button>  
 </form>
</body> 
<html>
```

Comment: @LGSon yeah in my example I have two columns `username` and `password` the first with the additional image. The names are more semantic then `<div>`. If you didn't know you can make up whatever tags you want, just FYI. If I'm missing something still be more clear and I can help you out.

Comment: @LGSon what are you even talking about lmao, there are 2 columns! do you know nothing? do I need to use `<columns>` so you can understand lmao.

Comment: @LGSon Yeah I can't understand... or simply you can't communicate... just because I'm not using the `.flexCol` class doesn't mean there not `flex-columns`, if you even looked at the CSS....

Answer (score -1):

Ok, here's a CSS-only solution for you:

```css
.flexForm {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 300px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .flexCol {
        flex-basis: 48.75%;
    }
    
    input[type="password"] {
        margin-top: 18px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="flexForm">
        <div class="flexCol">
            <label>Username Label That Wraps</label>
            <input>
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=10&txt=50x50&w=50&h=50">
        </div>
        <div class="flexCol">
            <label>password</label>
            <input type="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially, all I did was give the input box a top margin. The margin you use will depend on the height of each line in your label tags. In this case, this value is `18px`. But, if you change the font-size, you will have to calculate a new margin.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for may be doable with CSS.

Option 1 - No changes in html. Will work if the image size is known and you know for sure that just one of the label contents is going to wrap:

Based in the code you already have. Make the columns flex containers with flex-direction set to column, then justify-content to space-between. This way as both columns will have the height forced by the one with more content, the one with no image will have its content pushed away to the top and bottom. You just need to give to that input the same margin-bottom as the image height. It is easy to target that input as it will be the column last child.

Check the code snippet.

```css
form {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

div {
  min-width: 0%;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

div + div {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

label,
input,
img {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <form class="flexForm">
    <div class="flexCol">
      <label>Username Label That Wraps</label>
      <input>
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=10&txt=50x50&w=50&h=50">
    </div>
    <div class="flexCol">
      <label>password</label>
      <input type="password">
    </div>
  </form>
 
    <button>submit</button>
```

Option 2 - Needs html changes:

You just need to put the labels in a row and the rest of the contents in another row. Inside each of those rows you put your columns.

When the content one of the labels wraps and gets more height the row height grows pushing down the row below which content will keep the aligned as it sits in the same row.

```css
form {
  width: 300px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  min-width: 0%;
  flex: 1 0 0%;;
}

.column + .column {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


button {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
          <label for="firstInput">This is a very long label that wraps pushing the input down</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
          <label for="secondInput">This one is shorter!</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
          <input type="text" id="firstInput">
       <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=10&txt=50x50&w=50&h=50">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
          <input type="text" id="secondInput">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you miss _Without changing the basic structure of the two divs_?